# Trying to call last.fm Rest api for track.getSimilar, in python unable to comprehend the response

Tags: python, rest, request, last.fm

Here's my code:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://www.last.fm/api/show/track.getSimilar', params = {
"track": "Believe",
"artist": "Cher",
"limit": "5",
"api_key":"#my_api_key"})
```

`r.status_code` returns 200 which means call was successful. However when I try to print the response using `r.text`, I am not able to comprehend the response.

Comment: There is a python lastfm client: [`pylast`](https://github.com/pylast/pylast). You can use it instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Sure thanks I read about it. I am new to Python and am trying to understand how to these basics work and why the response to the above call isn't in the intended format. Any pointers in that direction would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to call the **documentation URL**; the returned page explains how to use the API< it is not the actual API method itself. Call the actual API at:

```
http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/
```

and give the method as a *parameter*:

```
params = {
    "method": "track.getSimilar",
    "track": "Believe",
    "artist": "Cher",
    "limit": "5",
    "api_key":"#my_api_key"
}
r = request.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/', params=params)
```

See the [API introduction](http://www.last.fm/api/intro):

> The API root URL is located at http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/

and the [REST requests documentation](http://www.last.fm/api/rest):

> Generally speaking, you will send a method parameter expressed as 'package.method' along with method specific arguments to the root URL. The following parameters are required for all calls:
>
> ***api_key*** : A Last.fm API Key.
>   ***method*** : An API method expressed as package.method, corresponding to a documented last.fm API method name.

Demo:

```
>>> import requests
>>> params = {
...     "method": "track.getSimilar",
...     "track": "Believe",
...     "artist": "Cher",
...     "limit": "5",
...     'api_key': '#a valid api key#',
... }
>>> r = requests.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/', params=params)
>>> r
<Response [200]>
>>> r.headers['content-type']
'text/xml; charset=utf-8;'
>>> r.content.splitlines()[1:3]
['<lfm status="ok">', '<similartracks track="Believe" artist="Cher">']
```

If you are using `requests` it may be easier to set the `format` parameter to `json`:

```
>>> params['format']= 'json'
>>> r = requests.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/', params=params)
>>> r.json()['similartracks']['@attr']
{u'track': u'Believe', u'artist': u'Cher'}
```

However, rather than re-invent the wheel, you could use the [`pyLast` module](https://github.com/pylast/pylast) instead:

```
import pylast
from itertools import islice


last = pylast.LastFMNetwork(api_key="#your_api_key", api_secret="#your_api_secret")
track = last.get_track('Cher', 'Believe')
for similar in islice(track.get_similar(), 5):
    # limited to the first 5 similar tracks
    print similar.item
```